# Make Windows 10 send the "computer name" as DHCP hostname

Tags: windows, windows-10, dns, dhcp

I'm running one linux machine and one Windows 10 machine on my OpenWRT wireless router. Both machine's names used to be "known" to the router, and I would be able to connect from one of them to the other using their respective hostnames. The Windows 10 machine used to show up with its "computer name".

As of recently, though, the router stopped showing a hostname of the  Windwos 10 machine and consequently, I cannot reach this machine via its hostname - only via tha IP address. The router's web interface shows its lease with a hostname of '?'. I probably changed something in its configuration, but I don't remember what exactly I did to it ...

So far, I've observed the network traffic of both machines at boot time: The Linux box uses the DHCP "hostname" option it its request, the Windows box doesn't. That might explain why the router never hears about it.

How do I configure the Windows 10 machine to announce its computer name as its hostname to the router?

Answer (score 0):

So, a "reset" of the network connection, including a re-install of the NIC drivers, seems to have solved the issue. What the actual setting was, I'll probably never know.